# Android Studio (Java) RecyclerView crashes when trying to parse JSON

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview

For the past few days I've been trying to implement a recyclerview into my mobile app that would display all the results with pictures. For this project I am using the spoonacular API.
My issue is that every time I try to run it the app crashes with the error message below. Before the error messages I can see that I am getting a response from the api but the recycler view is not inflating.

When I comment out the whole parseJSON() the view will come up but it's obviously just an empty page.

I have also tried `JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri.toString(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {` instead of the current `StringRequest`

Is the issue with my parse JSON function or am I looking at a completely wrong place and the adapter is causing the issue with the viewholder?

Logcat message:

```
2021-12-15 20:34:32.138 28763-28763/com.example.foodapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-12-15 20:34:32.142 28763-28763/com.example.foodapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.foodapp, PID: 28763
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2400)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1252)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:530)
        at com.example.foodapp.FoodsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FoodsAdapter.java:28)
        at com.example.foodapp.FoodsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FoodsAdapter.java:18)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
2021-12-15 20:34:32.142 28763-28763/com.example.foodapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

JSON result to search term "chicken"

```
{
    "results": [{
        "vegetarian": false,
        "vegan": false,
        "glutenFree": false,
        "dairyFree": false,
        "veryHealthy": true,
        "cheap": false,
        "veryPopular": false,
        "sustainable": false,
        "weightWatcherSmartPoints": 11,
        "gaps": "no",
        "lowFodmap": false,
        "aggregateLikes": 2,
        "spoonacularScore": 92.0,
        "healthScore": 90.0,
        "creditsText": "Foodista.com – The Cooking Encyclopedia Everyone Can Edit",
        "license": "CC BY 3.0",
        "sourceName": "Foodista",
        "pricePerServing": 168.12,
        "id": 654959,
        "title": "Pasta With Tuna",
        "readyInMinutes": 45,
        "servings": 4,
        "sourceUrl": "http://www.foodista.com/recipe/K6QWSKQM/pasta-with-tuna",
        "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/654959-312x231.jpg",
        "imageType": "jpg",
        "summary": "Pasta With Tuna might be just the main course you are searching for. One serving contains <b>421 calories</b>, <b>24g of protein</b>, and <b>10g of fat</b>. For <b>$1.68 per serving</b>, this recipe <b>covers 28%</b> of your daily requirements of vitamins and minerals. 1 person were impressed by this recipe. Head to the store and pick up flour, onion, peas, and a few other things to make it today. It is a good option if you're following a <b>pescatarian</b> diet. All things considered, we decided this recipe <b>deserves a spoonacular score of 92%</b>. This score is excellent. Try <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/pasta-and-tuna-salad-ensalada-de-pasta-y-atn-226303\">Pastan and Tuna Salad (Ensalada de Pasta y Atún)</a>, <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/tuna-pasta-565100\">Tuna Pasta</a>, and <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/tuna-pasta-89136\">Tuna Pasta</a> for similar recipes.",
        "cuisines": [],
        "dishTypes": ["lunch", "main course", "main dish", "dinner"],
        "diets": ["pescatarian"],
        "occasions": [],
        "analyzedInstructions": [{
            "name": "",
            "steps": [{
                "number": 1,
                "step": "Cook pasta in a large pot of boiling water until al dente.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 20420,
                    "name": "pasta",
                    "localizedName": "pasta",
                    "image": "fusilli.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 14412,
                    "name": "water",
                    "localizedName": "water",
                    "image": "water.png"
                }],
                "equipment": [{
                    "id": 404752,
                    "name": "pot",
                    "localizedName": "pot",
                    "image": "stock-pot.jpg"
                }]
            }, {
                "number": 2,
                "step": "Drain and return to warm pot. Put olive oil in saucepan and add onion.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 4053,
                    "name": "olive oil",
                    "localizedName": "olive oil",
                    "image": "olive-oil.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 11282,
                    "name": "onion",
                    "localizedName": "onion",
                    "image": "brown-onion.png"
                }],
                "equipment": [{
                    "id": 404669,
                    "name": "sauce pan",
                    "localizedName": "sauce pan",
                    "image": "sauce-pan.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 404752,
                    "name": "pot",
                    "localizedName": "pot",
                    "image": "stock-pot.jpg"
                }]
            }, {
                "number": 3,
                "step": "Saute until transparent. Stir in flour and cook for a few seconds and then whisk in milk. Stir constantly until this thickens.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 20081,
                    "name": "all purpose flour",
                    "localizedName": "all purpose flour",
                    "image": "flour.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 1077,
                    "name": "milk",
                    "localizedName": "milk",
                    "image": "milk.png"
                }],
                "equipment": [{
                    "id": 404661,
                    "name": "whisk",
                    "localizedName": "whisk",
                    "image": "whisk.png"
                }]
            }, {
                "number": 4,
                "step": "Add peas, tuna (shredded into chunks,) parsley, green onions, cheese and hot pepper sauce.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 6168,
                    "name": "hot sauce",
                    "localizedName": "hot sauce",
                    "image": "hot-sauce-or-tabasco.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 11291,
                    "name": "green onions",
                    "localizedName": "green onions",
                    "image": "spring-onions.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 11297,
                    "name": "parsley",
                    "localizedName": "parsley",
                    "image": "parsley.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 1041009,
                    "name": "cheese",
                    "localizedName": "cheese",
                    "image": "cheddar-cheese.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 11304,
                    "name": "peas",
                    "localizedName": "peas",
                    "image": "peas.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 10015121,
                    "name": "tuna",
                    "localizedName": "tuna",
                    "image": "canned-tuna.png"
                }],
                "equipment": []
            }, {
                "number": 5,
                "step": "Pour over pasta and stir gently to mix.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 20420,
                    "name": "pasta",
                    "localizedName": "pasta",
                    "image": "fusilli.jpg"
                }],
                "equipment": []
            }, {
                "number": 6,
                "step": "Serve at once.",
                "ingredients": [],
                "equipment": []
            }]
        }],
        "spoonacularSourceUrl": "https://spoonacular.com/pasta-with-tuna-654959"
    }, {
        "vegetarian": false,
        "vegan": false,
        "glutenFree": false,
        "dairyFree": false,
        "veryHealthy": false,
        "cheap": false,
        "veryPopular": false,
        "sustainable": false,
        "weightWatcherSmartPoints": 24,
        "gaps": "no",
        "lowFodmap": false,
        "aggregateLikes": 1,
        "spoonacularScore": 67.0,
        "healthScore": 28.0,
        "creditsText": "Pick Fresh Foods",
        "license": "CC BY 3.0",
        "sourceName": "Pick Fresh Foods",
        "pricePerServing": 274.82,
        "id": 511728,
        "title": "Pasta Margherita",
        "readyInMinutes": 45,
        "servings": 4,
        "sourceUrl": "http://pickfreshfoods.com/pasta-margherita/",
        "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/511728-312x231.jpg",
        "imageType": "jpg",
        "summary": "Pasta Margherita might be just the main course you are searching for. One serving contains <b>809 calories</b>, <b>34g of protein</b>, and <b>34g of fat</b>. This recipe serves 4 and costs $2.75 per serving. 1 person has made this recipe and would make it again. If you have basil, linguine pasta, garlic clove, and a few other ingredients on hand, you can make it. To use up the olive oil you could follow this main course with the <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/sauteed-banana-granola-and-yogurt-parfait-624619\">Sauteed Banana, Granolan and Yogurt Parfait</a> as a dessert. All things considered, we decided this recipe <b>deserves a spoonacular score of 69%</b>. This score is pretty good. Similar recipes include <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/margherita-pizza-with-pesto-pasta-salad-31919\">Margherita Pizza With Pesto Pasta Salad</a>, <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/pasta-margherita-with-rhubarb-and-apple-compote-613006\">Pasta margherita with rhubarb and apple compote</a>, and <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/margherita-pizzette-516272\">Margherita Pizzette</a>.",
        "cuisines": [],
        "dishTypes": ["lunch", "main course", "main dish", "dinner"],
        "diets": [],
        "occasions": [],
        "analyzedInstructions": [{
            "name": "",
            "steps": [{
                "number": 1,
                "step": "Whisk oil, garlic, basil, salt together in large bowl.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 11215,
                    "name": "garlic",
                    "localizedName": "garlic",
                    "image": "garlic.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 2044,
                    "name": "basil",
                    "localizedName": "basil",
                    "image": "basil.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 2047,
                    "name": "salt",
                    "localizedName": "salt",
                    "image": "salt.jpg"
                }, {
                    "id": 4582,
                    "name": "cooking oil",
                    "localizedName": "cooking oil",
                    "image": "vegetable-oil.jpg"
                }],
                "equipment": [{
                    "id": 404661,
                    "name": "whisk",
                    "localizedName": "whisk",
                    "image": "whisk.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 404783,
                    "name": "bowl",
                    "localizedName": "bowl",
                    "image": "bowl.jpg"
                }]
            }, {
                "number": 2,
                "step": "Add tomatoes and mozzarella then gently toss to combine; set aside.Cook pasta according to package directions for al dente.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 1026,
                    "name": "mozzarella",
                    "localizedName": "mozzarella",
                    "image": "mozzarella.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 11529,
                    "name": "tomato",
                    "localizedName": "tomato",
                    "image": "tomato.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 20420,
                    "name": "pasta",
                    "localizedName": "pasta",
                    "image": "fusilli.jpg"
                }],
                "equipment": []
            }, {
                "number": 3,
                "step": "Drain well.",
                "ingredients": [],
                "equipment": []
            }, {
                "number": 4,
                "step": "Add pasta to tomato mixture and gently toss to combine.",
                "ingredients": [{
                    "id": 11529,
                    "name": "tomato",
                    "localizedName": "tomato",
                    "image": "tomato.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 20420,
                    "name": "pasta",
                    "localizedName": "pasta",
                    "image": "fusilli.jpg"
                }],
                "equipment": []
            }, {
                "number": 5,
                "step": "Serve immediately.",
                "ingredients": [],
                "equipment": []
            }]
        }],
        "spoonacularSourceUrl": "https://spoonacular.com/pasta-margherita-511728"
    }],
    "offset": 0,
    "number": 2,
    "totalResults": 211
}
```

My RecyclerView Fragment

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private FoodsAdapter mFoodsAdapter;
    private ArrayList<FoodListItem> mFoodList = new ArrayList<FoodListItem>();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";


    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    public static final String ARG_FOOD_NAME = "foodName";
    public static final String ARG_DIET_PLAN = "dietPlan";

    private String mFoodName;
    private String mDietPlan;

    public RecyclerViewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param foodName the name of the food from user input.
     * @param dietPlan the diet plan selected on the spinner.
     * @return A new instance of fragment RecyclerViewFragment.
     */
    public static RecyclerViewFragment newInstance(String foodName, String dietPlan) {
        RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_FOOD_NAME, foodName);
        args.putString(ARG_DIET_PLAN, dietPlan);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mFoodName = getArguments().getString(ARG_FOOD_NAME);
            mDietPlan = getArguments().getString(ARG_DIET_PLAN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_view, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_foodlist);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new FoodsAdapter(mFoodList));

        mFoodList = new ArrayList<>();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(view.getContext());
        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        parseJSON();
    }

    private void parseJSON() {
        Uri uri = Utils.buildUri("https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=5da441b5a0254a19a401525d92b6cd73", "query", mFoodName, "addRecipeInformation", "true","number", "2");

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri.toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response);

                try {
                    // fetch JSONArray named results
                    JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = rootObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        mFoodList.add(new FoodListItem(result.getString("title"), result.getString("image"), result.getInt("readyInMinutes")));
                    }

                    mFoodsAdapter = new FoodsAdapter(mFoodList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFoodsAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.toast_error_downloading_food), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

My RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class FoodsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodsAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<FoodListItem> mFoodList;

    public FoodsAdapter(ArrayList<FoodListItem> foodList){
        mFoodList = foodList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FoodListItem currentItem = mFoodList.get(position);

        String imageUrl = currentItem.getImageUrl();
        String foodName = currentItem.getFoodName();
        int timeToMake = currentItem.getTimeToMake();

        holder.mTextViewFoodName.setText(foodName);
        holder.mTextViewTimeToMake.setText("Preparation time: " + timeToMake);
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().into(holder.mImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mFoodList != null)
        return mFoodList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextViewFoodName;
        public TextView mTextViewTimeToMake;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_title_image);
            mTextViewFoodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_food_name);
            mTextViewTimeToMake = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_food_time_to_make);
        }
    }

}
```

FoodListItem.java

```
public class FoodListItem {
    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mFoodName;
    private int mTimeToMake;

    public FoodListItem(String imageUrl, String foodName, int timeToMake) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
        mFoodName = foodName;
        mTimeToMake = timeToMake;
    }

    public String getImageUrl(){
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setFoodName(String inFoodName){
        this.mFoodName = inFoodName;

    }

    public String getFoodName(){
        return mFoodName;
    }

    public int getTimeToMake(){
        return mTimeToMake;
    }
}
```

Uri builder

```
    @NonNull
    public static Uri buildUri(String base, String paramName, String paramValue, String requestParamName, String requestParamValue, String numberOfItemsName, String numberOfItemsValue){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(base);
        // create a URI Builder and add the parameter
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = uri.buildUpon();
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(paramName, paramValue).appendQueryParameter(requestParamName, requestParamValue).appendQueryParameter(numberOfItemsName, numberOfItemsValue);
        return uriBuilder.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your adapter please check onBindViewHolder () you have to inflate a layout item in place of viewType , below code will run as per your requirement. please run the below code

/////////////My RecyclerView Fragment//////////////////////

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private FoodsAdapter mFoodsAdapter;
    private ArrayList<FoodListItem> mFoodList = new ArrayList<FoodListItem>();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    public static final String ARG_FOOD_NAME = "foodName";
    public static final String ARG_DIET_PLAN = "dietPlan";

    private String mFoodName = "foodName";
    private String mDietPlan = "dietPlan";

    private Uri buildUri(String base, String paramName, String paramValue, String requestParamName, String requestParamValue, String numberOfItemsName, String numberOfItemsValue) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(base);
        // create a URI Builder and add the parameter
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = uri.buildUpon();
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(paramName, paramValue).appendQueryParameter(requestParamName, requestParamValue).appendQueryParameter(numberOfItemsName, numberOfItemsValue);
        return uriBuilder.build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view_fragment);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_foodlist);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new FoodsAdapter(mFoodList));

        mFoodList = new ArrayList<>();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        parseJSON();
    }

    private void parseJSON() {
        Uri uri = buildUri("https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=5da441b5a0254a19a401525d92b6cd73", "query", "chicken", "addRecipeInformation", "true", "number", "2");

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri.toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response);

                try {
                    // fetch JSONArray named results
                    JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = rootObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        mFoodList.add(new FoodListItem(result.getString("image"), result.getString("title"), result.getInt("readyInMinutes")));
                    }

                    mFoodsAdapter = new FoodsAdapter(mFoodList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFoodsAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecyclerViewFragment.this, getString(R.string.toast_error_downloading_food), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

////////////// My RecyclerView Adapter/////////////////////

```
public class FoodsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodsAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<FoodListItem> mFoodList;

    public FoodsAdapter(ArrayList<FoodListItem> foodList) {
        mFoodList = foodList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.foods, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FoodListItem currentItem = mFoodList.get(position);

        String imageUrl = currentItem.getImageUrl();
        String foodName = currentItem.getFoodName();
        int timeToMake = currentItem.getTimeToMake();

        holder.mTextViewFoodName.setText(foodName);
        holder.mTextViewTimeToMake.setText("Preparation time: " + timeToMake);
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().into(holder.mImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mFoodList != null)
            return mFoodList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextViewFoodName;
        public TextView mTextViewTimeToMake;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_title_image);
            mTextViewFoodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_food_name);
            mTextViewTimeToMake = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_food_time_to_make);
        }
    }
}
```

//////Add foods.xml/////////

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_title_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/whatsappchatbackground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_food_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_title_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_food_time_to_make"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_title_image" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

//////////////FoodListItem.java/////////////

```
public class FoodListItem {
    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mFoodName;
    private int mTimeToMake;

    public FoodListItem(String imageUrl, String foodName, int timeToMake) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
        mFoodName = foodName;
        mTimeToMake = timeToMake;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setFoodName(String inFoodName) {
        this.mFoodName = inFoodName;

    }

    public String getFoodName() {
        return mFoodName;
    }

    public int getTimeToMake() {
        return mTimeToMake;
    }
}
```